# RecyclerView Item changes after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was trying to learn how to create a Recycler View, the first time when I followed a tutorial about it and hard-coded the contents of the items in the Recycler View everything worked fine; but when I moved the contents to strings.xml and sent the values something went wrong.
First the screen would be fine and appear like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS0b8.png) (keeping in mind that I have a total of six items), and after scrolling;
any item that goes off-Screen will change when it comes back like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcxcD.png), any help is grateful.

**note: when I removed the sixth item from my list everything was fine; because no item went off-Screen so no changes happened.**

**Main Acitivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecycler;
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private List<Contacts> contacts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    mRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerTut);

    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(false);

    DataEntry dataEntry = new DataEntry(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contact_names),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contact_numbers),
            getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.contact_photos));

    contacts = dataEntry.individualContacts();

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, contacts);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

}

**Adapter:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Contacts> mDataset;

public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<Contacts> myDataset) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}



@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_adapter, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.titleText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.subtitleText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getpNumber());
    holder.recyclerImage.setImageResource(mDataset.get(position).getImageSource());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView recyclerImage;
    public TextView titleText;
    public TextView subtitleText;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        recyclerImage = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_image);
        titleText = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_title);
        subtitleText = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_subtitle);
    }
}
```

**DataEntry:**

```
public class DataEntry {

private String []names;
private String []numbers;
private TypedArray photos;
private List<Contacts> indivisuals = new ArrayList<>();

public DataEntry(String[] names, String[] numbers, TypedArray photos) {
    this.names = names;
    this.numbers = numbers;
    this.photos = photos;
}

public List<Contacts> individualContacts(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++){

        int imageSource = photos.getResourceId(i, -1);
        indivisuals.add(new Contacts(names[i], numbers[i], imageSource));

    }

    return indivisuals;
}}
```

Comment: The only problem I can see here is that if you call individualContacts() twice the list will be doubled cause you dont clear the only instance of the 'indivisuals' list

Comment: Try to override `getItemViewType` in recyclerview and return `position`

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos well the list is actually not doubled in this case, and I can't really see where is the second call.

Comment: @LieForBananas no luck with that :(

Comment: Have you debugged your list and bindView method to see the position and getItemCount?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Scrolling down ignores positions: 1, 2 & 3 ... while scrolling up ignores positions: 4, 3 & 2. Size is always 6 ..

Comment: Did you debugged those or saying about behaviour?

Comment: solved by setting the height of single item layout from "match_parent" to "wrap_content"